# How to select rows with max values on a certain column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, aggregate-functions

For example, I have

```
tab1:
att1|att2
A|3
B|4
C|3
D|4
E|1
F|2
```

And I want

```
B|4
D|4
```

I know I can use

```
SELECT att1 att2
FROM tab1 as T
WHERE T.att2 =
(
   SELECT MAX(att2) FROM tab1;
}
```

I wondering if there is a more clever way to do it. B/c if it takes a complicated query to get tab1, it is cumbersome to write it twice.
By the way, I am using Sqlite.

Comment: what you've got is probably as good as it gets, performance- and cleanliness-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was:

```
SELECT att1, att2
FROM tab1
ORDER BY att2 DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

I apologize, that won't work if there is more than one record with the max value. Here is another answer:

```
SELECT t1.att1, t1.att2
FROM tab1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN tab1 AS t2
ON t1.att2 < t2.att2
WHERE t2.att1 IS NULL;
```

It's questionable whether this form is more efficient than nested SELECT the author mentioned, but might be better in case if tab1 is a select itself.

Comment: Thanks! However, if there are 10 values that have the maximum, that doesn't work...

Comment: Alexander - LIMIT will limit number of rows only. This is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex! That's clever.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, the problem is not the query itself but "cumbersome" writing table tab1.
I would suggest then you `create view tab1`, and then use it.

Comment: thanks! That will be the last thing that I can do. I just want to make sure there is no clever sql can do it in one pass.